# Input re-rendering and losing focus every time I type when using Formik

Tags: javascript, formik

When using FieldArray in Formik my inputs are always rerendered and thus they lose focus when a user types.

```js
   <FieldArray
      name="wallets"
      className="space-y-4"
      component={(arrayHelpers) => (
        <>
          {
            formik.values.wallets.map((wallet, i) => (
              <div
                key={i}
   {...}
```

Following the docs, Formik uses an index as the child `key`, which is not a good practice, but I don't have any other immutable value in the wallet to use (all of them might be changed within form). I believe the re-render is not a matter of using the index as a key but simply Formik re-rendering the whole mapped values each time a value changes.

Is there any way to prevent this to happen without being a huge hack?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just have to put a key that  should be permanent for the same component when props change

like this

```
   <FieldArray
      name="wallets"
      className="space-y-4"
      component={(arrayHelpers) => (
        <>
          {
            formik.values.wallets.map((wallet, index) => (
              <div
                key={`wallets.${index}`}
   {...}
```

**Solution :**

remove

```
key={i}
```

and do this

```
key={`wallets.${index}`}
```